# How to rename android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently published an app on google play store, but the name of the app is different when downloaded. After creating my app on Android studio, I renamed it on my developer console online, so the package name is different on Android studio.

I think that the package name might be causing the error, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to your Manifest and change the `android:label` to the name of your app

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>
```

However, it is supposed to have a default value of `"@string/app_name"` if you see this you should go res folder then values folder, inside the values folder you would see strings.xml in it you would see :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your app's Name</string>
</resources>
```

Then change the app name and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Your App Name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

     ...

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try these step if you want to just change the app name looking on your phone after installing.**

```
1.go to Value in res folder
2.in values goto String file
3.in String file 

change the app name    
<string name="app_name">LapiChat</string>
to
   <string name="app_name">yourApp_NAme</string>
```